# Reading row from one table and copy it to another table of database in Java

Tags: java, sql, database

I have 2 tables in my Java database. I would like to load rows from table1 and put them in table2. How can it be done please? I'm using `ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(SQL)` for reading from table I. What can I use to put this data to table II. ?

Comment: Do you know how to write an `INSERT` statement? You need to expand you explanation more.

Comment: IMHO, I would perform UPDATE on target table and SELECT from source table.

Answer (score 5):

Here you are:

```
String sql = "insert into table1 select * from table2 [where conditions]";
Statement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: hey, how about between two databases in sybase.. how can you do that?

Answer (score 1):

YOu can try something likethis:-

```
 Statement st1 = con1.createStatement();
 ResultSet rs = st1.executeQuery("select * from table1");
 PreparedStatement ps = null;

 while(rs.next())
    {
        ps = con2.prepareStatement("insert into table2 values(?,?)");
        ps.setInt(rs.getInt());
        ps.setString(rs.getString());
        ps.executeUpdate();
    }
```

Assuming that there are two columns in your table

Comment: You don't have to do this in java at all: `INSERT INTO table2 SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1`

Comment: @DigitalD: How would you do it without that?

Comment: @BheshGurung Sorry, I meant you wouldn't need to do it with an extra loop. You only need to execute the single SQL command.

Comment: @DigitalD: Yes you are right. A batch insert is the way to go here.

Comment: That was just one of the approach which struck my mind. I agree it can be done with a batch insert statement as well!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use PreparedStatments for this

Example Code Is here

```
 int result;
    Connection connection = null; // manages connection
            PreparedStatement insert = null;

    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,"root","password");
                insert = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT into table2" +
                "(f1,f2,f3)" +
                "VALUES(?,?,?)" );
                        insert.setString(1, Yourvaluehere);
                insert.setInt(2, Yourvaluehere);
                insert.setDouble(3, YourValueHere);
    result = insert.executeUpdate();
```

//Yourvaluehere - should come from the getmethods of the object - which is what i do, you can do something better if you have it in mind